# Angular 2 - is there any way to completely re-initialize a component upon resize window?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-components

I have a component ComponentA. there is some dom manipulation for deferent devices. I don't wanna fix them for every device when the browser resized.

that's why I wanna re-initialize the whole component again. is there any way to do it?

or any other solution would be very helpful.

thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to programatically destroy or re-initialize an component in Angular. An component will automatically be destroyed if there are no more variables or DOM elements referencing it.

EDIT: In order to solve your problem I'd suggest you have a look into the code nikolayandr posted.

Comment: Ahhh! that's why I couldn't find any solution for this and end up here posting a question.

anyway.. this clears some doubt though. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

if understood your question correctly then you can add just the next method to your component:

```
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    // event.target.screen.width is the current screen size
    // you can reinit your component here
  }
```

UPDATED.
Another way to catch window resize events is

```
import {FromEventObservable} from 'rxjs/observable/FromEventObservable';
import {debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators';

 initOnWindowResize() {

    FromEventObservable.create(window, 'resize')
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(500)
      )
      .subscribe((event: any) => {
        // Do something here
      });
   }

ngOnInit(): void {
        this.initOnWindowResize();
       });
```

Comment: I know how to catch resize event. but I don't know how to reinit the component.

but thank you anyway. :)